# Create a object with depenencies that have to be configured

Tags: php, design-patterns, client

I am creating a client using GuzzleHttp 5.3. I want use the same `Config` object to configure the *Guzzle Client*. So, the creation of *Guzzle Client* depends of the object `Config`.

For example:

```
$config = new Config([
    'user' => 'github',
    'password' => '1234',
    'base_url' => 'http://test_or_production_url.com'
]);

new GithubClient($config, new \GuzzleHttp\Client());
```

And the constructor:

```
public function __construct(Config $config)
{
    $this->authData = [
        'uname'     => $config->getUser(),
        'upassword' => $config->getPassword(),
    ];

    $this->config       = $config;
    $this->httpClient   = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_url' => $config->getBaseUrl());
    // I have to setup default headers, too.
}
```

But, I have to inject the *Guzzle Client* because I have to do *unit tests*.

One option is to inject a *Guzzle Client* configured as my client requires it. But the build process is a little cumbersome (set base_url, default header). The user must to know using *Guzzle*, I do not like this.

Other option is to create a new object (`GithubClientFactory` for example) to create my client.

```
$client = GithubClientFactory::make($config);
```

So, I hide the Guzzle dependency and the setup process. But the user always have to use the client factory.

Then, Is there a better (pattern) design to this problem?